# Getting window parameters with pywinauto (Top,Bottom,Right,Left)

Tags: pywinauto

Getting window parameters with pywinauto (Top,Bottom,Right,Left) I've managed to get these valuses using the following snippet of

`PrintControlIdentifiers()`

Taken from this documentation page on their github. https://pywinauto.github.io/docs/code/pywinauto.application.html#pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification.PrintControlIdentifiers

It does not quite do what I want it to do, it looks for an element in the application I am running. (The control identifier) and gives me the location for it on screen, using the following parameters.

(Top,Bottom,Right,Left)

My question is simple. Is there a function that works on a higher level, that dosen't go into elements of the window, but instead just prints the (Top,Bottom,Right,Left) value for the window you've opened and not it's elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `.Rectangle()` method and print its return value.

To get the hint on the list of available methods (in interactive mode) method `.WrapperObject()` is useful (in production it's called implicitly). Say you have

```
dlg = app.DialogName.WrapperObject()
```

Then you're able to type `dlg.` in IPython/IDLE/python.exe and get the list of available methods/properties for the window. Or just use `print(dir(dlg))`.

Comment: May I give my honest opinion on Pywinauto's documentation? Compared to a few other systems I've been using that aims to do similar things, Pywinauto's have been the hardest to navigate. I would call it rather user unfriendly.

But this is merely my constructive criticism. It would do it a lot of good to have the library updated.

Comment: You are right. The docs is a weakness of pywinauto. We're working on improvements for the next release.